# How to bind item outside the itemsource?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a listview with itemSource from viewModel but i need to bind a label text in this listview to outside the itemSource

```
     <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding reports, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped" 
                VerticalOptions="Center" SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
                  SeparatorColor="Black" x:Name="listview">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                    <Frame Padding="0.20" Margin="2">

                            <Grid x:Name="gridview">

                            <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Governerate}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <BoxView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding VisitCount}" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="visitcounts" TextColor="Red"/>
                            <BoxView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding item outside itemsource}" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <Label  Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That easy you do it something like this:

First, give your ListView a name(Already there)

Then In the Binding use that name as a Reference for the Binding Context:

```
Text="{Binding Path=BindingContext.YourItem, Source={x:Reference listview}}"
```

Where `YourItem` is the Name of your string Property outside the `ItemsSource`